# Error using Cursor in MySQL with subquerys

Tags: mysql, cursor, handle

I have the following stored procedure:

```
DECLARE CURSORITO CURSOR FOR SELECT  issues.id FROM issues

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '02000' SET done=1;

OPEN CURSORITO;

REPEAT
FETCH CURSORITO INTO c_id ; 

IF NOT done THEN
    -- TOTAL HOURS
    SELECT SUM(hours) INTO c_Tot_Horas FROM time_entries WHERE issue_id=c_id;
    INSERT INTO TOTAL (ID,TOT) VALUES c_id,c_Tot_Horas ;
END IF;
UNTIL done END REPEAT;
```

But when the "Total Hours Querys" no have data , the process exit from the repeat section, setting the "Done" variable in true

How should I do to get the process done well, that is, walking around all the cursor?

Comment: probably because SUM(hours) returns `null` ..Try replacing it with `IFNULL(SUM(hours),0)`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a cursor for this.

```
INSERT INTO total(ID, TOT)
SELECT issue_id, SUM(hours) 
FROM time_entries t
/*optionally you can add*/
INNER JOIN issues i ON t.issue_id = i.id
/*if you need to filter by joining*/
GROUP BY issue_id
```

Cursors are very slow, avoid them at all costs when you don't need them.